# Displaying wrong data after scrolled TableView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, fmdb

I tried to update TableView cell when click cell from `CollectionView` with key word of class.
For example, when I click "all", it should perform all data.
When I click "a", it should perform class with "a".
It looks like all perfect until I scroll down TableView.
All data display which is not my intension, it should only show specify data even scroll up/down TableView.
Is it related to `dequeueReusableCell` issue?

I use `FMDB` to query data when click `CollectionView` cell.
I attach gif

[image]

and hope it could be better to understand my problem.

Can someone help me out with this please? Thanks.

add cellForRow function here.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell

    if navigationItem.searchController?.isActive == true{
        cell.itemImage.image = searchArray[indexPath.row].thumbnailImage()
        cell.nameLBL.text = "name：\(searchArray[indexPath.row].name ?? "")"
        cell.quantityLBL.text = "Qty：\(searchArray[indexPath.row].quantity ?? 0)pcs"
        cell.amountLBL.text = "amount：\(searchArray[indexPath.row].amount ?? 0)"
        cell.dateLBL.text = "date：\(searchArray[indexPath.row].date ?? "")"
        cell.storeLBL.text = "store：\(searchArray[indexPath.row].store ?? "")"
        cell.classLBL.text = "class：\(searchArray[indexPath.row].itemClass ?? "")"
        if let reminder = searchArray[indexPath.row].reminder {
            let reminderText = ""
            cell.reminderLBL.text = "\(reminder)" + reminderText
            reminderStatus = true
        }else{
            cell.reminderLBL.text = "reminder：NO"
            if self.array[indexPath.row].reminder == nil{
                cell.reminderLBL.text = "reminder：NO"
            }
            reminderStatus = false
        }

    }else{

        cell.itemImage.image = array[indexPath.row].thumbnailImage()
        cell.nameLBL.text = "name：\(array[indexPath.row].name ?? "")"
        cell.quantityLBL.text = "Qty：\(array[indexPath.row].quantity ?? 0)pcs"
        cell.amountLBL.text = "amount：\(array[indexPath.row].amount ?? 0)"
        cell.dateLBL.text = "date：\(array[indexPath.row].date ?? "")"
        cell.storeLBL.text = "store：\(array[indexPath.row].store ?? "")"
        cell.classLBL.text = "class：\(array[indexPath.row].itemClass ?? "")"
        if let reminder = array[indexPath.row].reminder {
            let reminderText = ""
            cell.reminderLBL.text = "\(reminder)" + reminderText
            reminderStatus = true
        }else{
            cell.reminderLBL.text = "reminder：NO"
            if self.array[indexPath.row].reminder == nil{
                cell.reminderLBL.text = "reminder：NO"
            }
            reminderStatus = false
        }
        print(array.count)
    }
    return cell
}
```

add didSelectItemAt function here.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        reloadTableViewAndDatabase()
    case 1:
       reloadTableViewAndDatabase(itemClass: searchStringOfDaily)
    case 2:
       reloadTableViewAndDatabase(itemClass: searchStringOfCare)
    case 3:
        reloadTableViewAndDatabase(itemClass: searchStringOfCosmetic)
    default:
        reloadTableViewAndDatabase()
    }
}
```

And function which may be factor.

```
let searchStringOfDaily = "SELECT * FROM Data where itemClass = 'a';"
let searchStringOfCare = "SELECT * FROM Data where itemClass = 'b';"
let searchStringOfCosmetic = "SELECT * FROM Data where itemClass = 'c';"

func reloadTableViewAndDatabase()
{
    self.dbHelper.searchAllDataFromDatabase { (dataArray) in
        self.array = dataArray
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func reloadTableViewAndDatabase(itemClass:String)
{
    self.dbHelper.searchDataFromDatabase(completionHandler: { (dataArray) in
        self.array = dataArray
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }, search: itemClass)
}



public func searchDataFromDatabase(completionHandler:([Data]) -> (),search:String) {

    var searchResultArray:[Data] = []
    if self.database == nil{
        self.database = FMDatabase(path: self.databasePath)
    }
    if self.database.open(){
        let searchString = search
        do{
            let resultNext = try self.database.executeQuery(searchString, values: nil)
            while resultNext.next(){
                let dataName = resultNext.string(forColumn: "name")
                let dataQuantity = resultNext.int(forColumn: "quantity")
                let dataAmount = resultNext.int(forColumn: "amount")
                let dataDate = resultNext.string(forColumn: "date")
                let dataStore = resultNext.string(forColumn: "store")
                let dataImageName = resultNext.string(forColumn: "imageName")
                let dataItemClass = resultNext.string(forColumn: "itemClass")
                let dataReminder = resultNext.string(forColumn: "reminder")

                let data = Data(name: dataName!, quantity: Int(dataQuantity), amount: Int(dataAmount), date: dataDate!, store: dataStore!, imageName: dataImageName ?? "", reminder: Int(dataReminder!), itemClass: dataItemClass!)
                searchResultArray.append(data)
            }
            print("query success")
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.database.close()
    }
    completionHandler(searchResultArray)
}
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of refreshController in your tableView?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you use to populate the table.  It's hard to guess without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: @emrepun No I do not set refreshConrollter

Comment: @PhillipMills I updated just now, hope it is clear...

Comment: The code suggests that either the search controller is not active or `searchArray` has the wrong contents.  Do you see `array.count` being printed when you scroll?  Can you set a breakpoint before scrolling and see what code is being executed in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: Wait....  In `reloadTableViewAndDatabase(itemClass:String)`, should it be `self.searchArray = dataArray`?

Comment: @PhillipMills I firstly clicked CollectionViewCell and array.count show 1 which is correct, but then I scrolled down the array.count go back to 3. In reloadTableViewAndDatabase(itemClass:String, I cannot assign self.searchArray as they are not in same class. By the way, searchArray is for SearchController, and I did not type word in searchController.

Comment: Unrelated but getting the **same** item from the array (`array[indexPath.row]`) 8 (eight!) times is unnecessary inefficient and you are strongly discouraged from using `Data` as name for a custom class.

Comment: If those are different classes, then how is `array` in one supposed to become `array` in the other?

Comment: @vadian Thanks for advice! As I am new for Swift, I will keep in mind and avoid name Data as custom class, but what do you mean that getting same item from array eight times?

Comment: @PhillipMills My bad. They are actually in same class, but as you can see  **SearchArray** is use for **SearchController**, if I change **self.searchArray = dataArray**, every CollectionViewCell I clicked will show all Data.

Comment: Rather than getting the item by index from the array 8 times write **once** `let item = array[indexPath.row]` and then `item.name`, `item.quantity` etc.

Comment: @vadian Got it! thanks for advice!